# Making aliases for terminal in OSX Lion

Tags: terminal, alias, scp

I want to be able to type this in:

```
myscpalias ~/file.txt .
```

in order to execute this command:

```
scp myusername@server.com:~/file.txt .
```

---

I'm also not sure how wo go about the following. I want to type in:

```
cd mypath
#or something like:
scp mypath/file.txt myusername@server.com:~/folder
```

in order to actually do:

```
cd /blah1/blah2/blah3/ 
#or something like:
scp /blah1/blah2/blah3/file.txt myusername@server.com:~/folder
```

I've been having trouble making aliases do do this. Do I even need an alias or should I be using a function? I've tried many combinations of things and I can't get it to work. I'm on OSX Lion and putting the aliases in my .profile file. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your shell is `bash` (the default) then the alias syntax is this:

```
alias myalias='this is my command'
```

For example:

```
alias dir1='cd /blah1/blah2/blah3/'
```

...would allow you to type `dir1` to perform the above `cd` command.

You're right that functions are also an option and they're probably better for things that are more complicated or multi-line, such as the parameterized `scp`.

For example:

```
myscpalias() {
  host=$1
  dir=$2
  # should add error checking, such as:
  if [ "x$host" = "x" ] ; then
    echo "host is required" >&2
  else
    scp myusername@server.com:${host} ${dir}
  fi
}
```